# Shutting down the Windows 7 installer (before the actual installation) correctly

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

A couple of days ago my sister bought my niece a new laptop. They called me to ask for my opinion and I told them the laptop was too expensive for its specs and they got ripped off; no problem, since the shop has a refund policy if the product has never been used.

The product has NEVER been used but my niece turned on the PC just once before calling me, and since it came with Windows 7, the Windows 7 installer started. She did not install Windows 7 and it's everything as new, the problem is that there is no way to shut down the Windows 7 installer without using the Power button, triggering a hard-shut down and launching the Windows Error Recovery on startup.

Being aware that the store from which they bought the laptop is very strict on refunds and does inspect the computers, I think I can take no chance unless that Windows Error Recovery goes away. But I know no way of shutting down the Windows 7 installer without turning the power off directly. There is no shutdown button and pressing the shutdown button on the keyboard once doesn't do anything.

My sister could not consult me when she bought the laptop and she's not very good with technology, she's a single mother and I don't want her to throw her hard earned money to some greedy people only because Microsoft decided that you can't shutdown the system unless you install Windows 7. Maybe they did it on purpose, I don't know. Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a way to shut down the Windows 7 installer (currently locked on the "Select your language" screen, the installer did not install anything yet) without triggering a Windows Error Recovery.

Comment: [An answer for windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/a/818933/348490) that may also work here (not sure)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried continuing the install and then disagreeing to the EULA when it's offered to you?  The response to 'No I don't agree" is usually to shut off.

Keep in mind, if that is a notebook that comes with both 32 and 64-bit versions of Windows on it, and you get to choose at first boot (Toshiba does this), and you picked one the first time you turned it on, then they'll know regardless of how you shut it down now.

Why not call the shop and let them know what's going on, instead of trying to scam them?  If it's not abused and they can re-box it, they'll probably be fine taking it back as-is -- maybe with a small restocking fee to cover the time/taxes on it.

If the place you purchased it are being jerks, call the notebook manufacturer for help/suggestions.

Comment: I'm not trying to scam them - they're trying to scam me. Pressing a single button on a laptop shouldn't be considered "use" it. I'm giving it back after two of their offered seven days. My niece is 10 and she didn't know better. I referred to them as "strict" but they indeed are jerks - I'd never buy from them, my sister did. A question: when does the EULA screen come? Before or after it asks for the user name? Because I didn't get past that screen afraid that it would create an user I wouldn't be able to remove unless I installed W7.

Comment: I was thinking about this, and depending on the notebook OEM, you may have already agreed to the EULA by splitting a sticker someplace on the packaging to use the notebook, since you have the notebook available to you, you'd have to tell me if that was done. :)  Regardless, I'd still call the store.  If they offer 7 days, then it's probably 'no questions asked'.  Because if they were going to reject your return claim after only about an hour of use, then they'd probably reject it as 'not broken' just as easily. :)

Comment: Ok, I will. I'm sure that they will say "if she opened it, it can't be refunded", though. After all, they're so incompetent they're probably going to freak out as soon as they see "Windows ERROR RECOVERY"  and tell my sister to screw herself, or offer her to get another identical one. They're really scummy and the articles they sell the most are those $50 HDMI cables that do nothing better than cheap HDMI cables. They are the only electronic shop in a small town and they get away with pretty much everything.They also buy Chinese stuff from Ebay and sell it at 10x the price. They're total scum.

Comment: If in the end it comes down to them rejecting it, then perhaps the silver lining is the education your sister will gain.  ;)

Comment: Well, I guess a month's salary is too much for that. I was out of town and my niece needed a computer so she went to the only shop in town. They have an absolute monopoly and probably won't give any refunds. It's a shame that they would rip off a working woman so shamelessly and it's also a shame her child will feel guilty for the great expense. I wasn't even going to use W7! I taught my niece to use Linux very soon. But anyway you did your best to help me, thanks.

Comment: The Romans have a saying for this. Caveat Emptor.  I hardly think the manufacturer is scamming anyone.  No one forced you to open your wallet in the first place. . .

Answer (score 0):

If it came with a plain Windows 7 install, you can reset the state to "System out-of-box experience" with `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\SysPrep.exe`

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this or a bit more info about how it would work?

Answer (score 0):

Have they actually said they won't accept it back, or are we just assuming they will unless it's pristine? I've worked for a computer store and have experience with several others and I can't say I've ever experienced a store as "aggressive" as the one you describe. I'd counsel you to try to return it as is. If they don't take it back find your local equivalent of an alderman and let them go at it. Or if there is a local tv station with a consumer watch team, they'd probably love to heckle the store with bad publicity if you were to bring your story to them.